# Unable to justify text using writeHTMLCell

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to print some text with HTML tag using TCPDF `writeHTMLCell()` function. Although, it prints in a desired format, but what is missing is the alignment. I want the alignment as justify. I am using the following code. One solution is to reduce the font size but that I want to keep the font size. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$html='<p align="justify">LOREMIPSUMDOLORSITAMETCO<span style="background- 
color: #add8e6; color: #000;">NSECTETURADIPIS</span>CINGELITSEDDOEIU<span 
style="background-color: #f0e68c; color: 
#000;">SMODTEMPORIN</span>CIDIDUNTUTLABORE<span style="background-color: 
#ffc0cb; color: #000;">ETDOLOREMAGNAA</span>LIQUAUTENIMADMINIM</p>';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(180, 6,15, 160, $html, 0, 1, 1, true, 'J' ,false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a style attribute:

```
<span style="text-align:justify;">...</span>
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Tks